# Translating Jquery nav function to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I need to convert Jquery to JavaScript function to get a better understanding. It is supposed to be a sticky navigation function. Here is the code:

class StickyNavigation {

```
constructor() {
    this.currentId = null;
    this.currentTab = null;
    this.tabContainerHeight = 70;
    let self = this;
    $('.et-hero-tab').click(function() {
        self.onTabClick(event, $(this));
    });
    $(window).scroll(() => { this.onScroll(); });
    $(window).resize(() => { this.onResize(); });
}

onTabClick(event, element) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let scrollTop = $(element.attr('href')).offset().top - this.tabContainerHeight + 1;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollTop }, 600);
}

onScroll() {
    this.checkTabContainerPosition();
    this.findCurrentTabSelector();
}

onResize() {
    if(this.currentId) {
        this.setSliderCss();
    }
}

checkTabContainerPosition() {
    let offset = $('.et-hero-tabs').offset().top + $('.et-hero-tabs').height() - this.tabContainerHeight;
    if($(window).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.et-hero-tabs-container').addClass('et-hero-tabs-container--top');
    }
    else {
        $('.et-hero-tabs-container').removeClass('et-hero-tabs-container--top');
    }
}

findCurrentTabSelector(element) {
    let newCurrentId;
    let newCurrentTab;
    let self = this;
    $('.et-hero-tab').each(function() {
        let id = $(this).attr('href');
        let offsetTop = $(id).offset().top - self.tabContainerHeight;
        let offsetBottom = $(id).offset().top + $(id).height() - self.tabContainerHeight;
        if($(window).scrollTop() > offsetTop && $(window).scrollTop() < offsetBottom) {
            newCurrentId = id;
            newCurrentTab = $(this);
        }
    });
    if(this.currentId != newCurrentId || this.currentId === null) {
        this.currentId = newCurrentId;
        this.currentTab = newCurrentTab;
        this.setSliderCss();
    }
}

setSliderCss() {
    let width = 0;
    let left = 0;
    if(this.currentTab) {
        width = this.currentTab.css('width');
        left = this.currentTab.offset().left;
    }
    $('.et-hero-tab-slider').css('width', width);
    $('.et-hero-tab-slider').css('left', left);
}
```

}

new StickyNavigation();

I tried translating it, however I keep failing and I guess my knowledge of JavaScript is still not great yet (i'm a beginner with vanilla javascript). I would appreciate the help!